# What does cooking have to do with graph paper?

Tags: feature-request

Just wondering about the choice of background image. It hurts my eyes to have so many lines that don't align with any of the implied grids on the page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just a temporary theme for when the Cooking site is in the beta phase. In fact, all Stack Exchange beta sites use this sketchy theme. Once out of beta, each site will have their own themes. Also see:

[Will all Stack Exchange sites look the same?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55529/will-all-stack-exchange-sites-look-the-same)

Answer (score 0):

Gingham tablecloth fabric could make a suitable substitute.

Comment: Aha! The Better Homes and Gardens look is **your fault**!!